# Music flat sign shows extra padding and increases line height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When using the musical flat sign (♭) on a mobile browser, it renders an extra space before it and it seems to mess up the line height too. I've tried

- Different fonts (still happens with no specified font)
- `font-kerning: (none|normal|auto);`
- The `letter-spacing` property, which fixes it on the phone, but breaks it on the desktop.

Is there anything I can do to fix this bar using images?

Here are some screenshots.

Chrome desktop:

[image: Chrome Desktop]

Chrome mobile (Notice the boxes aren't all the same size and there is a space before the ♭):

[image: Chrome Mobile]

Comment: can you demo it using a fiddle?

Comment: You can check it out here with no registration: http://darajava.ie:1301/scales

Answer (score -1):

This reason of this kind of occurrence to happen lies on the line-height property.
You can inspect this behavior with google inspect tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) with google chrome.

you can easily see that those "higher" cells are getting the extra height from the font itself (not from the padding,margin or anything else).

Just add:

```
line-height: 1;
```

It will cause the font height to be fixed.

*note : use letter-spacing property inside media query to target only mobile screen.

Comment: That will only fix the box height. The main problem is getting rid of the spaces before the flats.